# XCode Intellisense Question

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense

I've always seem to work around this lack of knowledge but I thought I would ask the community.  I hope this question will make sense.

In XCode, when I call a function that has several parameter the intellisense pops up.  When I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> the first time, it takes me directly to the first parameter. How do I get to the next parameter easily. If I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it puts an actual <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the line. For the last month I've been using arrow keys but I figured there must be a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I'm using a Windows keyboard too so if you know the Windows shortcut, that would be what I need.

Comment: That *really* doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

There is an array shortcut for this; I believe it is ^/ by default, but it's configurable (in Preferences > Key Bindings > Edit > Select Next Placeholder) so I might have changed it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

If you type:

> self.

and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, [you will see the list of all members](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2008/12/29/xcode-intellisense-shortcut/).